# Email signature displaying incorrectly in certain clients

Tags: html-table, html-email, thunderbird

I am working on a fairly simple email signature. I have not done this before and am trying to build something that will display correctly in as many email clients as possible. Two issues I have been made aware of at the moment are: Images not being displayed for some, and also users in Thunderbird have reported some display issues. If anything looks immediately obvious I would really appreciate your input! The annotated code is shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:white;background-image:none;background-
    repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;font-
    family:'ARIAL', sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:normal;" >



 <div style="padding-top:1em;padding-bottom:4em;padding-right:0;padding-
    left:0;" >

  <div style="width:600px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-
        right:auto;margin-left:auto;" >


   <!-- Personal information -->
   <div  style="display:table;" >

    <!-- Name -->
    <h1 style="color:#34CF42;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-
                right:0;margin-left:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;padding-
                top:20px;" >Joe blogs</h1>
    <!-- End Name -->

    <!-- Role -->
    <h2 style="color:#9B9B9B;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-
                right:0;margin-left:0;font-size:12px;font-weight:500; padding-top: 
                3px;" >Job title</h2>
    <!-- End Role -->


    <!-- Personal - Phone numbers and links-->
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

     <tr style="padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-
                    right:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-top:0;margin-
                    bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;">

      <td nowrap>
       <a href="tel:#" style="font-size:20px; color:#1F80BA; 
                            display:table-cell;vertical-align:top; text-
                            decoration:none !important;"  > <h3 style="white-
                            space: nowrap;color:#FF00FF;margin-top:0;margin-
                            bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;font-weight:500; 
                            font-size:12px; text-decoration:none !important; 
                            padding-top: 5px;padding-right:5px;">+44&#173; 123 456 
                            7890 |</h3></a>
      </td>

      <td nowrap>
       <a href="tel:#" style="font-size:20px; color:#1F80BA; 
                            display:table-cell;vertical-align:top; text-
                            decoration:none !important;"  > <h3 style="white-
                            space: nowrap;color:#FF5521;margin-top:0;margin-
                            bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;font-weight:500; 
                            font-size:12px; text-decoration:none !important; 
                            padding-top: 5px;padding-right:5px;">+44&#173; 
                            78910111212 </h3></a>
      </td>

     </tr>

    </table>

    <!--End Personal - Phone numbers and links -->

    <!-- Spacer -->
    <br>
    <!-- End Spacer -->

   </div>
   <!-- End Personal information -->


   <!-- information -->

   <table>
    <tr>
     <!-- logo -->
     <td width="60" style="padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px; vertical-
                    align:top;">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img 
                        src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60"></a>
     </td>
     <!-- end logo -->

     <!-- left hand info -->
     <td>
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <h1 style="color:#1f354a;margin-top:0;margin-
                                    bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;font-
                                    size:12px;font-weight:700;" >Insert strapline 
                                    here</h1>
         <td>
         </tr> 

         <tr>
          <td>
           <h2 style="color:#9B9B9B;margin-
                                            top:3px;margin-bottom:0;margin-
                                            right:0;margin-left:0;font-
                                            size:12px;font-weight:500;" >Insert 
                                            another statement here</h2>
           <td>
           </tr>

           <!-- social icons -->
           <tr>
            <td>
             <table>
              <tr>
               <td>
                <a 
          href="https://placeholder.com"><img 
          src="http://via.placeholder.com/14x14"></a>
               </td>

               <td>
                <a 
          href="https://placeholder.com"><img 
          src="http://via.placeholder.com/14x14"></a>
               </td> 
              </tr>
             </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- end social icons -->
         </td>

        </tr>

       </table>

       <!-- End information -->



       <!--Spacer-->
       <br>
       <!--End Spacer-->




       <!--Small print-->
       <div  style="color:#898989;display:table; font-
      size:10px" >
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error 
     sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
     ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta 
     sunt explicabo.
       </div>
       <!--End small print-->


      </div>


     </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having, it will be easy for me to help.

Comment: I am looking to find out if there is any reason (based on my code) that some email clients would not show the images. I am also looking for more general advice if anyone spots anything that may cause an issue in a particular email client.

Comment: I cannot see an extension in your images i.e. `http://via.placeholder.com/14x14` , it might be the issue.

Comment: I do not think it is the image links that are causing the issue as I copied that link directly from placeholder.com and have never had an issue doing this in the past. The images also display perfectly when I view the code locally.

Comment: for the images, you NEED to add the extension of the file type: `http://via.placeholder.com/60x60.png` as most email clients won't know what to do with just the `60x60`

Comment: @Callum It will display properly in your browser, but some email clients have very different and unique way of displaying images, in case of email clients everything needs to be mentioned like the image extension, they aren't smart like our browsers, just try adding extension.

Comment: So I have swapped out the images for placeholders for the purposes of sharing the code publicly, in the original email signature the image extensions are there. The images are linked correctly. I suppose my question is, based on the above code and the method used (embedding images using a URL) is there any reason why certain image clients may not display the images? Or would the reason for this be that the recipient has opted to hide images in their email settings?

Comment: I'm seeing an 'Error, file name not specified' error in GMail on Chrome in place of embedded images.